$\log(K/\beta+1)$, $K\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, is asymptotically normal as $\lambda\to\infty$?
Previously posted on the MSE here.
For $K\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $\beta>0$ let
$$
Y=\log(K/\beta+1).
$$
Using first-order Taylor expansion on $Y$ we obtain
$$
\tilde Y=\log(\lambda/\beta+1)+\frac{K-\lambda}{\lambda+\beta}
$$
so that
$$
\mathsf E\tilde Y\approx\log(\lambda/\beta+1)
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{Var}\tilde Y\approx\frac{\lambda}{(\lambda+\beta)^2}.
$$
Defining
$$
Z=\frac{Y-\mathsf E\tilde Y}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}\tilde Y}}=\frac{\lambda+\beta}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\log\left(\frac{K/\beta+1}{\lambda/\beta+1}\right),
$$
is it true that
$$
Z\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal N(0,1)
$$
as $\lambda\to\infty$?

This should be easy to show if you write $K$ as the sum of $\lambda$ i.i.d. $\mathrm{Poisson}(1)$ random variables (with trivial modifications when $\lambda$ is not an integer).

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\be\beta$Yes, this is true. Indeed, on the event $A_\la:=\{|K-\la|\le\la^{5/8}\}$,
$$Z=Z_\la:=\frac{\la+\be}{\sqrt\la}\,
\ln\Big(1+\frac{K-\la}{\la+\be}\Big) \\ 
=\frac{\la+\be}{\sqrt\la}\,
\Big(\frac{K-\la}{\la+\be}+O\Big(\frac{(K-\la)^2}{\la^2}\Big)\Big)\\
=\frac{K-\la}{\sqrt\la}+O\Big(\frac{(K-\la)^2}{\la^{3/2}}\Big) \\ 
=\frac{K-\la}{\sqrt\la}+O\Big(\frac1{\la^{1/4}}\Big) \\
=\frac{K-\la}{\sqrt\la}+o(1),$$
and $P(A_\la^c)\le E(K-\la)^2/\la^{5/4}=\la^{-1/4}\to0$, where $A_\la^c$ is the complement of $A_\la$, so that $Z_\la\,1_{A_\la^c}\to0$ in probability and hence in distribution (as $\la\to\infty$).
Also, $\frac{K-\la}{\sqrt\la}\to V$ in distribution, where $V$ is a standard normal random variable. So,
$$Z_\la
=\Big(\frac{K-\la}{\sqrt\la}+o(1)\Big)\,1_{A_\la}
+Z_\la\,1_{A_\la^c}.$$
Thus,
$$Z_\la\to (V+0)(1-0)+0=V$$
in distribution. $\quad\Box$

Thank you, Iosif. Could you explain the choice of $A_\lambda$ and where the inequality for $P(A_\lambda^c)$ comes from?

$A_\lambda$ was so chosen because it works this way, and the inequality is an instance of the Chebyshev inequality.
